# Optimize Jquery script

Tags: jquery

I try to optimize this code :

```
     $(".carre").each(function(){

    if ($(this).attr('taille') == '3-1') {
        $(this).height(a*3).width(b*1);
        $("a", this).height(a*3).width(b*1);
    } 

     if ($(this).attr('taille') == '1-3') {
        $(this).height(a*1).width(b*3);
        $("a", this).height(a*1).width(b*3);
    } 

    if ($(this).attr('taille') == '2-1') {
        $(this).height(a*2).width(b*1);
        $("a", this).height(a*2).width(b*1);
    } 

    if ($(this).attr('taille') == '2-3') {
        $(this).height(a*2).width(b*3);
        $("a", this).height(a*2).width(b*3);
    } 
 });
}
```

I tried this :

```
     $(".carre").each(function(){

     var str = $(this).attr('taille');
     var h = str.charAt(0);
     var w = str.charAt(str.length-1);
        $(this).height(a*h).width(b*w);
        $("a", this).height(a*h).width(b*w);});
```

But doesn't work for all, just for one class.

Can you help me please,

Best regards

Comment: do you have any errors in the console? where are `a` and `b` defined?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the values from the string using `split`:

```
var values = "3-1".split("_");
```

Then you can access values[0] and values[1] in your calculations.